# Concentration inequality for hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, bounds, hypergeometric-distribution

Let a population $C$ consist of $N$ values $c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_N$, with $c_i\in \{0,1\}$. Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ denote a random sample without replacement from $C$ and let $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_n$ denote a random sample with replacement from $C$. The random variables $Y_1, \cdots, Y_n$ are independent and identically distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, where
$$
\mu=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N c_i, \quad \sigma^2=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N\left(c_i-\mu\right)^2
$$
Chernoff give upper bounds for $\operatorname{Pr}\{\vec{Y}-\mu \geq t\}$, where $\bar{Y}=\left(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n\right) / n$. Hoeffding proved ([Theorem 4 of this paper](https://mathoverflow.net/q/261077/433582))that the same bounds are upper bounds for $\operatorname{Pr}\{\bar{X}-\mu \geq t\}$, where $\bar{X}=\left(X_1\right.$ $\left.+\cdots+X_n\right) / n$.

**Question**

$\text { In the case above we have } E \bar{X}=E \bar{Y}=\mu \text { but } \operatorname{Var} \bar{X}=\frac{N-n}{N-1} \frac{\sigma^2}{n}<\frac{\sigma^2}{n}=\operatorname{Var} \bar{Y}$.

Both distribution are symmetric and share a common expected value.  [In this case doesn't the variance already show how concentrated the random variables are around the mean?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/261077/433582) Why isn't it obvious that the concentration inequalities for $\bar{Y}$ would also hold for $\bar{X}$? Why did Hoeffding had to prove his result?

Imagine instead of $n$ samples with replacement, we made $n'$ samples with replacement, for some $n'>n$. In this case, $E \bar{X}=E \bar{Y}=\mu \text, \operatorname{Var} \bar{X}=\frac{N-n}{N-1} \frac{\sigma^2}{n},\operatorname{Var} \bar{Y}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n'}$. If we maximise $n'$ such that $\operatorname{Var} \bar{X}<\operatorname{Var} \bar{Y}$ still holds, that would yield a concentration inequality tighter than Serfling. The following figure plots size of the sampled block vs the probability that the mean of the sample deviates from the mean of the population by a certain amount. The dots are the result from simulation. The blue line is from using Additive chernoff with $n'=n (N-1)/(N-n)$ and orange is from Serfling.
[image]

Comment: A variance is not a probability and therefore does not directly indicate "concentration" in the sense of the tail probability bounds used here.

Comment: I understand that, however intuitively I feel like there is a connection. Since both distributions are symmetric with the same mean, the tail bound should be larger for the one with the larger variance right? Is there any counter example to this?

Comment: There are loads of counterexamples.  But there are connections between variance and tail bounds in the form of inequalities: a sufficiently small variance guarantees a sufficiently small chance of exceeding a large deviation from the mean.  Chebychev's Inequality is perhaps the best known and most widely used one of these inequalities.